# Open an ajax modalpopup with details from gridview cells

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, gridview, modalpopupextender

I've got a gridview with a appointment information in.  What I want to do is have a linkbutton in each cell (which will be created at runtime) and open a modal popup showing the details of the appointment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So far I've got, but it won't fire the linkbutton

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" onrowdatabound="Grd_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView><asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" style="display:none" runat="server"  />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender
ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="ImgCancel" ></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" Width="400px" ><!--Show Details--!>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCancel"  AlternateText="cancel"  Height="25" Width="25" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" />
</asp:Panel>
```

code behind

```
protected void Grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Split out the visit details & format
            for (int i = 0; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.Text = "Details for:" + "<br />" + e.Row.Cells[i].Text; 

                lnk.CommandName = "ShowDetails";
                lnk.Command += LinkButton_Command;
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(lnk);


            }



        }
    }
    protected void LinkButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ShowDetails")
        {

            LinkButton btndetails = sender as LinkButton;

            GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;

            this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Where\when do you currently call `BindData()` on your gridview?

Comment: on Page Load if it's not postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is that you need to make sure that the dynamic `LinkButton` controls are recreated on the postback in order for the event to be properly wired. Since you create the `LinkButtons` within the `Grd_RowDataBound` handler, which only gets called when you call `BindData()` (and you're not calling it on postback), your events won't wire.  So if you're code looks something like this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     Grd.BindData();
}
```

Try removing the `if(!IsPostBack)` check, and always call BindData() on Page_Load.

Comment: Hi thanks that works, however, because it's reloading the page and binding the grid each click, it's really slow.

Answer (score 0):

In your modal popup, the only content should be an empty iframe. Then write a javascript function as follows:

```
function showPopup(target, link, width, height)
{
    var frame = document.getElementById('popupIframe');
    frame.src = link;
    frame.width = width;
    frame.height = height;
    var location = Sys.UI.DomElement.getLocation(target);
    var popup = $find('Popup');
    popup.set_X(location.x);
    popup.set_Y(location.y);
    popup.show();
}
```

Then in your link button add:

```
OnClientClick="showPopup(this, your_details_page_with_querystring_params, width, height)
```